# Core Wars 8086 safe challenge

Tags: assembly, x86-16, corewars

I'm doing a safes competition and I created this safe:

```
start:

mov bx, 0

label:
mov cx, [1234]
inc cx
shl cx, 1
mov [1234], cx
dec cx
shl cx, 1
dec cx
loop label
          
mov bx, cx 
mov [bx], ax
jmp start
```

Im need to create the key of this safe, but i dont know how to.

This simulation of a safe and key is done inside the Core Wars 8086 engine. The rules are as follows where both safe and key are survivors in the war:

> The survivors cannot place a load on fixed addresses, because the game
> engine loads them every turn to a random address. The programs that
> are generated must be COM and not EXEs and contain only 8086
> instructions.
>
> Each survivor receives a set of its own complete registers
> (registers), which is not accessible to the other survivors. In
> addition, each survivor has a "personal" stack of 2048 bytes, which is
> also inaccessible to the other survivors.
>
> Before running the first round of the game, the game engine
> initializes all the bytes in the arena to the value 0CCh (note: this
> byte value is an "unsupported" instruction - details below). The
> engine then loads each survivor to a random location in the arena
> memory, ie - copies the contents of the survivor file exactly as it
> is. The distance between two survivors, as well as the distance
> between the survivor and the edge of the arena, is guaranteed to be at
> least 1024 bytes. The code for each survivor has a maximum of 512
> bytes.
>
> Before the first round, the game engine initializes the registers (of
> each survivor) to the following values:
>
> - BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, BP - Reset.
> - Flags - Reset.
> - AX, IP - The position of the initial survivor, the random offset in    the arena to which the survivor is loaded by the game engine.
> - CS, DS - The segment of the arena common to all survivors.
> - ES - A segment (segment) for the memory shared by survivors of the    same group (see Advanced Techniques ).
> - SS - Beginning section of the personal stack of the survivor.
> - SP - Offset The start of the personal stack of the survivor.
>
> At this point the game begins in rounds, with each round running the
> game engine running the next instruction of each survivor, until the
> end of the game: after 200,000 rounds, or when a single survivor
> remains in the arena. The order in which the survivors will play in
> each round is determined at the beginning of the game at random, and
> does not change during it.
>
> A survivor is disqualified in the following cases:
>
> - Running an illegal instruction (example: byte 060h that does not    translate into any assembly instruction).
> - Running an "unsupported" instruction by the game engine (example:    "INT 021h"). The game engine prevents running instructions that try
>   to initiate direct communication with the operating system or
>   computer hardware. Attempt to access memory that is not within the
>   realm of the arena, and not within the realm of the "personal" stack
>   of the survivor.
> - Attacking other survivors is done by writing information about their    code in the arena memory (in order to get them to perform one
>   of the    above three actions), and consequently to disqualify them.
>   Earlier,    therefore, one has to find where they are hiding :)

Comment: `shl cx, 2` is not a valid 8086 instruction, you have to repeat `shl cx, 1` twice instead. (The other 8086 compatible way is using `cl` as shift count but that cannot work with `cx`.)

Comment: I still don't understand the goal of the game or what a safe and a key are. There is no reference to them in the quoted text. What is the goal of the survivors? They executed interleaved and then what? Also, since this is a competition, shouldn't you do this alone? Isn't this cheating?

Comment: "I need to create the key of this safe, but I don't know how to" is not really a question — are you asking about some assembly instruction usage, address space or memory layout, game operation?